# Create two indicator (dummy) variables

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

Create a new dataframe (call it C1) that is a copy of Carseats.

Create two indicator (dummy) variables:

Bad_Shelf = 1 if ShelveLoc = “Bad”, 0 otherwise

Good_Shelf = 1 if ShelveLoc = “Good”, 0 otherwise

Code in R:

```
#Load the dataset carseats(in the ISLR Package) into R.Studio

library(ISLR) #load and attach the package
View(Carseats) #view the data
data("Carseats") #loads the data "Carseats"
str(Carseats) #compactly displays the internal structure of the object

#(A) Make a new dataframe (Call it C1) that is a copy of carseats

C1 <- data.frame(Carseats)

#(B) Create two indicator (dummy variables) 
#(B.1) Bad_Shelf = 1 if ShelveLoc = "Bad", 0 otherwise

Bad_Shelf <- ifelse(ShelveLoc = "Bad", 1, 0)

Good_Shelf <- ifelse(ShelveLoc = "Good", 1, 0)

**Error in ifelse(ShelveLoc = Bad, 1, 0) : 
  unused argument (ShelveLoc = Bad)
```

Comment: You need to use `==` instead of `=` ie `ifelse(ShelveLoc == "Bad", 1, 0)`

Comment: Thanks Onyambu - I tried your fix but...received this error message:                      > Bad_Shelf <- ifelse(ShelveLoc == "Bad", 1, 0)
Error in ifelse(ShelveLoc == "Bad", 1, 0) : object 'ShelveLoc' not found                  it seems I am having an issue getting R to find the object ShelveLoc despite it being a defined column in the "Carseats" dataset.

Comment: then you do `ifelse(C1$ShelveLoc == "Bad", 1, 0)`

Comment: It's only with `dplyr` and related sets of functions that you can supply bare column names of a data frame, and that's after passing a data frame into a function. You need to refer to `Carseats$ShelveLoc`, because on its own `ShelveLoc` has no meaning

Comment: thank you onyambu. this time it worked. is it correct to say that "C1$ShelveLoc" uses the $ operator in R to identify ShelveLoc from the dataframe C1?

Comment: @dpoak Have a read of the help file `?"["` and `?"[.data.frame"`. The information contained in each is quite useful if you plan on using R for a considerable amount of time. I recommend reading them a couple of times over a few months.